# Connection String for MS Access Database incorrect

Tags: vba, connection, ms-access-2010

I am trying to extrapolate data from an MS Access 2007/2010 Database.

I have the following code in VBA but the connection string is incorrect. I have added the relevant REFERENCES libraries

```
 Private Sub btnGetMsAccessData_Click()

Dim sConn As String
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String

sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\MyNetworkPath\BP-MasterDashboard Source\BP_Planning_by_PT_dept_be.accdb;Mode=Read"

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection        ' Open a connection.
oConn.Open


sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Start_Leaver"        ' Make a query over the connection.
Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset
oRs.Open sSQL, , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText

MsgBox oRs.RecordCount

oConn.Close ' Close the connection.
Set oConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

It fails saying Unknown Application error on the oConn.Open line.

I have tried to link a Workbook to one of the tables and this works fine. 
I then looked at the "Connection" and copied it into my code but still no joy.

Keeps saying :
Automation Error
Unexpected Error

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While the connection string was incorrect, there were other issues as well. Such as, not assigning the connection String to the ADODB Connection object as well as others. Here is the updated code that I hope will get you operational

```
Private Sub btnGetMsAccessData_Click()
    'Ensure you add a reference to Microsoft ADO Objects
    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRs   As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSQL  As String: sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Start_Leaver"
    'Corrected Connection String from Thomas Inzina
    Dim sConn As String: sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;UID=Admin;Data Source=" & _
                                 "\\MyNetworkPath\BP-MasterDashboard Source\BP_Planning_by_PT_dept_be.accdb;Mode=Read"

    With oConn
        .ConnectionString = sConn ' You need to assign the connection string to the ADODB.Connection Object
        .Open
    End With

    'Make sure the connection isn't open before opening the recordset
    'You also need to specify which connection you want to use as the second parameter (this was missed)
    If oRs.State <> adStateOpen Then oRs.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText

    'Close Connection and RS
    If oConn.State = adStateOpen Then oConn.Close
    If oRs.State = adStateOpen Then oRs.Close

    'Clean Up
    Set oRs = Nothing
    Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This has not worked. I am thinking maybe its a lib reference that I need.

Comment: See my comment on line 2 of the code. You need a reference to ADO. Specifically `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Library` or you may have version 6.x available. Either should work.

Comment: I have Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library - so it appears this is not the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the specific error you are receiving, and on what line.

Comment: I have even tried connecting to the Northwind.mdb and this does not work either. Most strange. :(

Comment: It might be the connection string still. I didn't need the UID portion to connect. `Dim sConn As String: sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\MyNetworkPath\BP-MasterDashboard Source\BP_Planning_by_PT_dept_be.accdb;Mode=Read"`

Comment: Run Time Error '-2147467259

Automation Error  
Unspecified Error